# remove first two bytes of a line

Tags: text-processing

I have a file that has 2 bytes of binary indicator values in every row that has to be stripped off.

I tried `sed`, `awk`, `cut` but none of them work (though they work in `vi` mode):

```
sed 's/^.\{,2\}//' file.dat
awk '{print substr($0,3)}' file
cut -c3-  file
```

Example:

```
<84>^cColumn1,Column2
x^CColumn1,Column2
v^CColumn1,Column2
<81>^CColumn1,Column2
```

Desired Output:

```
Column1,Column2
Column1,Column2
Column1,Column2
Column1,Column2
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `cut`:

```
cut -b 3- infile
```

This will cut the first 2 bytes from each line or print from 3<sup>rd</sup> byte to end of line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `^C` character that you present on each line is an actual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is an actual ETX "end of text" character (hex 0x03), you could use:

```
sed 's/^.*\o3//' file
```

If it is a simple `^C` string, the use:

```
sed 's/^.*^C//' file
```